# Why ChartJs is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, chart.js

The VueJs chart application in this example does not work in IE. Does anyone know why?

For example, the following component does not print errors but does not run at the same time

```
<div class="app">
    {{ message }}
  <line-chart></line-chart>
</div>


  Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }

})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

Comment: do you see any error in the console? This link has some examples to check
https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/echarts/

Comment: I bet it's a library/polyfill that you'll need to track down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, there is one ES6 syntax is being used to define object method in your component, at this line :

```
mounted () {
```

... and ES6 syntaxes are not supported in Internet Explorer yet.

Instead, you would have to use ES5 syntax all over your component/app, if you wish to support IE :

```
Vue.component('line-chart', {
   extends: VueChartJs.Line,
   mounted: function() {  //<- use this instead
      this.renderChart({
         labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
         datasets: [{
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
         }]
      }, {
         responsive: true,
         maintainAspectRatio: false
      })
   }
});
```

see a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uj60259a/).

Comment: The Microsoft company is often advertising its own broken browser in its own operating system. I think they continue to insist on a project that will never succeed.